# Microsoft Edge の質問にはどのタグが適切か？

Tags: 討議, タグ

ブラウザの一つ、Microsoft Edge に関する質問を時折見かけるので個別タグを割り当てたいのですが、"適切なタグ名" は何が良いかで悩んでいます。

少しややこしいことに、名前は同じままバージョンによってブラウザエンジンが異なります。

- EdgeHTML エンジン
- Blink エンジン (Chromium版)

参考までに、姉妹サイトではどのようになっているかというと…

- Stack Overflow

  - [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge)
  - [microsoft-edge-chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge-chromium)

  使い分けは曖昧で、あまり徹底もされていない様子
- Server Fault
  [microsoft-edge] のみ
- Super User
  [microsoft-edge] のみ

---

今後は "Chromium版" の方が話題に上がることが多そうですが、上記も踏まえてスタック・オーバーフローにおいてはどの様にタグ付けするのが適切でしょうか？

- [microsoft-edge] のみ使う
- [microsoft-edge], [microsoft-edge-chromium] で使い分ける
- [microsoft-edge-legacy], [microsoft-edge] で使い分ける
- その他 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

現状 ["edge is:question" で検索しても 117 件のみのヒット](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=edge%20is%3Aquestion)であり、これからもタグを分けるほど質問数が来ると思えないので、[microsoft-edge](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) のみで良いのではないかなと考えています。